# Поиск строки с preg_match

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!

Как взять всю строку (ссылку) с preg_match через следующий код:

```
preg_match('#<div id="download.*">(.*)</div>#siU', $file, $dl);
```

Comment: `phpQuery` используйте.

Comment: `preg_match` -> `preg_match_all`, `(.*)` -> `(.*?)`

Comment: @Webmaster Регулярные выражения не предназначены для парсинга HTML.

Comment: Ваш паттерн соответсвует большому куску разметку с многими ссылками https://pastebin.com/Ze56vMSa . О какой начальной ссылке вы говорите?

Answer (score 0):

Полный синтаксический анализ HTML невозможен с помощью регулярных выражений, поскольку он зависит от соответствия открывающих и закрывающих тегов, которые невозможно использовать с регулярными выражениями.

Регулярные выражения могут соответствовать только [обычным языкам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), но HTML - это [контекстно-свободный язык](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Единственное, что вы можете делать с регулярными выражениями в HTML, - это эвристика, но это не будет работать при каждом условии. Должно быть возможно представить HTML-файл, который будет неправильно сопоставлен любым регулярным выражением.

Comment: @Webmaster это значит нужно использовать phpQuery и CSS селекторы